# Redirect URL with ?aid=ind/234/ to third party URL with #affid

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to redirect my page from `abc.com/page.html?aid=ind/234/` to `xyz.com/pagename#affid`

I want to do this by adding meta redirect or any javascript that run locally on `abc.com/page.html`

I do not want to use htacess.

Please help me out.

Best Regards

Comment: So what has your research turned up so far, what have you tried …?

Comment: I tried meta refresh but it doesn't pass #affid means xyz.com/pagename opens without #affid

Comment: And same result for a basic JS “redirect”, `location.href = "..."` …?

Comment: please provide the exact code and where to put it?

Comment: Please stop asking for “the exact code”, and do some _proper research_ instead. Then _try_ stuff, and tell us what the outcome was.

Comment: i tried it but it didn't work, that's why i asked for the exact code. no worries if you don't want to specify the code.

Comment: Then _show us_ what you tried, by editing it into your question.

Answer (score -1):

use php for getting request parameter: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php
and redirect to needed page like here:
[How to make a redirect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Enjoy